# Why a Timer variable assigned with time.Afterfunc executes its function even though outer func exits

Tags: go, concurrency, timer, goroutine

I have a forever loop that has a Timer variable that executes a function after some time.

```
package main

import (
    fmt "fmt"
    "time"
)

func exe() {
    fmt.Println("10-seconds-of-time-is-done")
}

func t() {
    var timerCheck *time.Timer
    fmt.Println("here's the timerCheck", timerCheck)
    for {
        timerCheck = time.AfterFunc(10*time.Second, func() { exe() })
        fmt.Println("exiting-from-function-t")
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    t()
    fmt.Println("waiting-inside-main")
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
}
```

This is the output. I don't understand the function `t()` returns immediately but `timerCheck` executes its `exe()` function after 10 second.

```
here's the timerCheck <nil>
exiting-from-function-t
waiting-inside-main
10-seconds-of-time-is-done
```

How is this possible? In the standart library, it says as follows regarding `AfterFunc`

```
// AfterFunc waits for the duration to elapse and then calls f
// in its own goroutine. It returns a Timer that can
// be used to cancel the call using its Stop method.
func AfterFunc(d Duration, f func()) *Timer {
    t := &Timer{
        r: runtimeTimer{
            when: when(d),
            f:    goFunc,
            arg:  f,
        },
    }
    startTimer(&t.r)
    return t
}
```

I expect everything related timerCheck` should be freed since outer function's job is done, basically this function's stack is freed (I guess :/).

In order to check stack/heap allocations, the output is as follows;

```
./main.go:9:13: ... argument does not escape
./main.go:9:14: "10-seconds-of-time-is-done" escapes to heap
./main.go:14:13: ... argument does not escape
./main.go:14:14: "here's the timerCheck" escapes to heap
./main.go:16:47: func literal escapes to heap
./main.go:17:14: ... argument does not escape
./main.go:17:15: "exiting-from-function-t" escapes to heap
./main.go:24:13: ... argument does not escape
./main.go:24:14: "waiting-inside-main" escapes to heap
```

`func literal escapes to heap` is it because of this, so that `exe` function still runs?

I need some internal guidance here regarding how does this `timerCheck` and `exe()` function still works after 10 seconds? even though the function `t()` returns immediately. I didn't expect this log to be printed `10-seconds-of-time-is-done`. Because function `t()` is done already.

Example code is executable and can be tried.

Comment: The documentation of AfterFunc might be misleading: Calling AfterFunc is not like "sleep d; f()". AfterFunc returns immediately because to just sleep for d you do not need any tooling.

Answer (score 5):

The timer variable lives even after the function declaring it returns, because the timer creates a goroutine referencing to it. The goroutine waits for the given duration, sends its signal or calls the AfterFunc, and then terminates. Only after that the timer variable can be garbage collected. The AfterFunc executed asynchronously.